# How do I mock a method which uses elementree methods for parsing xml

Tags: python, mocking, elementtree

I need to write a unit test using Mock module for a Python code with different functions:

- `_read_file()`: opens a URL and then parse the xml using Element tree and return element tree instance.
- `validate_field`: this filed takes arguments as field_value and order.
  `tree.findall` function is used to get all `fields_values` in a list and then using the order exact value of that field is stored in a field. this file is then compared with the received argument and based on comparison either true of false is returned.

I have written unit test for above function. I have mocked `urllib.urlopen` and the return value of the called function, but it's giving error as:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please guide me on this.

Code below:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, host, service_path='/policy/test.xml'):
        self.base_url = 'https://' +host + service_path
        self.service_path = service_path
        self.host = host

    def _read_policy(self, url):
        policy_xml = urllib.urlopen(url)
        self.tree = ElementTree.parse(policy_xml)
        return self.tree

    def compare(self, arg1, arg2):
        if arg1 == arg2:
            return 'true'
        else:
            return 'false'

    def validate_email(self, email, order):
        index = int(order) - 1
        email_list = self.tree.findall("testList/test/email")
        xml_email = email_list[index].text
        _resp = self.compare(xml_email, email)
        return(_resp)
```

Test class:

```
class test_validate_email(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_validate_email(self):
        myMock = Mock( return_value = StringIO.StringIO("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><email>*@test.com</email>"""))
        urllib.urlopen = myMock
        print 'urllib.urlopen', urllib.urlopen()

        cp = test(DEFAULT_HOST)
        tree = cp._read_policy("some data")
        ElementTree.dump(tree)

        myMock2 = Mock(return_value = 'true')        
        _resp = myMock2
        print 'test_resp', _resp()

        resp = cp.validate_email('*@ashishtest.com','1')
        print 'resp', resp
        self.assertEqual(resp, 'true')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Seems the problem is in _read_policy, try different parse function.